# Import CSV file into Grid View in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, csv, gridview, import

How to load the CSV file dynamically inside Grid View in C# Asp.net without hard coded values?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (File.Exists(myFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName))
            {
                string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(myFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string[] col = data[0].Split(',');

                foreach (string s in col)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(s, typeof(string));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] row = data[i].Split(',');
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                myGridView.DataSource = dt;
                myGridView.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: Let me know if anyone needs the whole application code. thanks! :)